# IPC communications in different computers using shared memory

Tags: c, concurrency, ipc, real-time

i need to write c code for two processes in different host(computers) communicate using shared memory in Linux .

I know how to do this in the same computers but i different i do not know how.

Comment: Excluding exotic hardware (e.g. non-transparent bridges) memory can only be shared by processes in the same computer (because remote computers don't have direct access to memory). To get good answers you're going to need to ask a good question - specifically, is exotic hardware involved, or are you talking about 3 processes (shared memory between 2 processes on the same computer with a remote third process), or are you trying to do something impossible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't communicate between two processes in different machine using shared memory ,you need to do socket programming for communicating between two different machines.

Please refer http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/ for your reference

Comment: i need to access the shared memory from one process

Comment: Just a note - on Windows shared memory can be mapped to network disks thus providing shared access, but the images are not synchronized, so such feature can't be used for communicating efficiently.